# Mouse Hover using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to hover the **mouse over** this menu

[Click On it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSTTt.jpg) can you tell me how can I **hover mouse** to another **submenu** inside this **main menu**?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Comment: I am using selenium web driver with java.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `foo.html`:

```
<a id="foo" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#FF0000'"  onMouseOut="this.style.color='#0abab5'" >Don't do this for real</a>
```

Here are some contrived examples in python and ruby (with a plug for the `watir` gem).

In each example, you'll see required imports/requires and a browser instantiation.

After getting the test page and the test element, a call is made to the `ActionChains` class and `action` method in python and ruby, respectively.

Lastly, a call to the `perform()`/`perform` method.  And--in `watir`--the sequence is encapsulated in a `hover` method.

selenium-webdriver with python bindings:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('file:///C:/so/foo.html')

element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)  
hover.perform()
```

selenium-webdriver with ruby bindings:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to 'file:///C:/so/foo.html'

element = driver.find_element(id: 'foo')

driver.action.move_to(element).perform
```

watir:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto 'file:///C:/so/foo.html'
b.link(id: 'foo').hover
```